# ChartJS Tooltips with time axis and multiple datasets

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

So i have a bar chart set up to display two different datasets that take place at more or less the same time, but have some missing data from hour to hour:
[image: Image of sample chart]
The data in this graph is stored in the format `{x:timestamp, y:value}`, and bars are all located at the correct positions, however some of the tooltips are wrong:
[image: Second sample chart]
In this example, my mouse is highlighted over the "1AM" bar for dataset "0", yet the timestamp says it is at 9:00 AM, and the 9:00 bar for dataset "1" is highlighted. Also, the data displayed in the tooltip (1.279) is actually correct for 1AM, not 9.

From what I can tell, this seems to happen because there is a different number of data points in each dataset, and the "index" mode for tooltips doesn't handle this correctly. The data for this chart is below:

```js
{
  backgroundColor: "rgba(240, 80, 45, 0.63)",
  borderColor: "#f0502d",
  label: "1",
  data:[
  {
    "x": 1589497200000,
    "y": 0.014
  },
  {
    "x": 1589500800000,
    "y": 0.003
  },
  {
    "x": 1589504400000,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 1589536800000,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 1589540400000,
    "y": 0.023
  },
  {
    "x": 1589544000000,
    "y": 0.251
  },
  {
    "x": 1589547600000,
    "y": 0.599
  },
  {
    "x": 1589551200000,
    "y": 0.896
  },
  {
    "x": 1589554800000,
    "y": 1.582
  },
  {
    "x": 1589558400000,
    "y": 2.335
  },
  {
    "x": 1589562000000,
    "y": 1.302
  },
  {
    "x": 1589565600000,
    "y": 2.774
  },
  {
    "x": 1589569200000,
    "y": 2.432
  },
  {
    "x": 1589572800000,
    "y": 1.257
  },
  {
    "x": 1589576400000,
    "y": 0.056
  }
]},
{
[
  label:"0",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(217, 217, 216, 0.63)",
  borderColor: "#d9d9d8",
  data:{
    "x": 1589497200000,
    "y": 0.014
  },
  {
    "x": 1589500800000,
    "y": 0.003
  },
  {
    "x": 1589504400000,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 1589536800000,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 1589540400000,
    "y": 0.023
  },
  {
    "x": 1589544000000,
    "y": 0.251
  },
  {
    "x": 1589547600000,
    "y": 0.599
  },
  {
    "x": 1589551200000,
    "y": 0.896
  },
  {
    "x": 1589554800000,
    "y": 1.582
  },
  {
    "x": 1589558400000,
    "y": 2.335
  },
  {
    "x": 1589562000000,
    "y": 1.302
  },
  {
    "x": 1589565600000,
    "y": 2.774
  },
  {
    "x": 1589569200000,
    "y": 2.432
  },
  {
    "x": 1589572800000,
    "y": 1.257
  },
  {
    "x": 1589576400000,
    "y": 0.056
  }
]}
```

And the options for this chart: (note that CustomTooltips is just

```js
{
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                intersect: true,
                mode: 'index',
                position: 'nearest',
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            scales: {

                xAxes: [
                    {
                        type:"time",
                        distribution:"series",
                        offset:true,
                        time:{
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            maxRotation: 0,
                            maxTicksLimit: 12,
                        }
                    }],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            maxTicksLimit: 8,
                        }
                    }],
            },
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 0,
                    hitRadius: 10,
                    hoverRadius: 4,
                    hoverBorderWidth: 5,
                },
            },
        }
```

So my question is: how can I get the tooltips displaying the correct times and correct values?

I could switch the tooltip mode to "x", but then the tooltip only displays for one bar at a time, rather than the bars for both datasets that happen at the same time, so I'd rather not do this.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem may be related to a buggy version of Chart.js. Therefore makek sure to use the latest stable version of the library (currently [v2.9.3](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.3)).

Your code looks fine to me. Nevertheless I made the following slight changes to it.

...removed the `elements` object from the chart `options`.

...defined `xAxis.time` as follows to make sure, the hours in the tick labels and in the tooltip are of the same format.

```
xAxes: [{
  type: "time",
  ...
  time: { 
    unit: 'hour',
    tooltipFormat: 'hA' 
  },
```

Please have a look at your amended runnable code below.

```js
const datasets = [{
    backgroundColor: "rgba(240, 80, 45, 0.63)",
    borderColor: "#f0502d",
    label: "1",
    data: [{
        "x": 1589497200000,
        "y": 0.014
      },
      {
        "x": 1589500800000,
        "y": 0.003
      },
      {
        "x": 1589504400000,
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 1589536800000,
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 1589540400000,
        "y": 0.023
      },
      {
        "x": 1589544000000,
        "y": 0.251
      },
      {
        "x": 1589547600000,
        "y": 0.599
      },
      {
        "x": 1589551200000,
        "y": 0.896
      },
      {
        "x": 1589554800000,
        "y": 1.582
      },
      {
        "x": 1589558400000,
        "y": 2.335
      },
      {
        "x": 1589562000000,
        "y": 1.302
      },
      {
        "x": 1589565600000,
        "y": 2.774
      },
      {
        "x": 1589569200000,
        "y": 2.432
      },
      {
        "x": 1589572800000,
        "y": 1.257
      },
      {
        "x": 1589576400000,
        "y": 0.056
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "0",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(217, 217, 216, 0.63)",
    borderColor: "#d9d9d8",
    data: [{
        "x": 1589497200000,
        "y": 0.014
      },
      {
        "x": 1589500800000,
        "y": 0.003
      },
      {
        "x": 1589504400000,
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 1589536800000,
        "y": 0
      },
      {
        "x": 1589540400000,
        "y": 0.023
      },
      {
        "x": 1589544000000,
        "y": 0.251
      },
      {
        "x": 1589547600000,
        "y": 0.599
      },
      {
        "x": 1589551200000,
        "y": 0.896
      },
      {
        "x": 1589554800000,
        "y": 1.582
      },
      {
        "x": 1589558400000,
        "y": 2.335
      },
      {
        "x": 1589562000000,
        "y": 1.302
      },
      {
        "x": 1589565600000,
        "y": 2.774
      },
      {
        "x": 1589569200000,
        "y": 2.432
      },
      {
        "x": 1589572800000,
        "y": 1.257
      },
      {
        "x": 1589576400000,
        "y": 0.056
      }
    ]
  }
];

const options = {
  tooltips: {
    enabled: true,
    intersect: true,
    mode: 'index',
    position: 'nearest',
  },
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom'
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: "time",
      distribution: "series",
      offset: true,
      time: { 
        unit: 'hour',
        tooltipFormat: 'hA' 
      },
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true
      },
      ticks: {
        maxRotation: 0,
        maxTicksLimit: 12,
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        maxTicksLimit: 8,
      }
    }],
  }
};

new Chart("barChart", {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: datasets
  },
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="barChart" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: hmm, I was using an outdated version of chartjs, but updating that to 2.9.3 (and react-chartjs-2 to 2.9.0) and making the changes you describe, I'm still getting the same issue, maybe it's a problem with react-chartjs-2 then?

Comment: actually, your snippet only works because the data lines up correctly, add {"x":1589493600000,"y": 1} to only one of the datasets to see what i mean